# Issue with Coinbase-API cbpro Websocket order submission

Tags: python, api, websocket, algorithmic-trading, coinbase-api

trying to use the websocket from cbpro to submit orders and for some reason it is not working, it works on_open and on_close or as a standalone definition but does not work on_message as part of the running websocket

code example:

```
def web_socket_testing(): 
 class myWebsocketClient(cbpro.WebsocketClient):
    def on_open(self):
        self.auth_client = cbpro.AuthenticatedClient(api_key, api_secret, passphrase)


    def on_message(self, msg):
        if some criteria....
            self.auth_client.place_market_order(product_id='xxx', side='xxx', size='xxx') 

wsClient = myWebsocketClient()
wsClient.start()
time.sleep(7000)
wsClient.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  web_socket_testing()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work?" Does it raise an error? And please try to refrain from theoretical code like `if some condition`

Comment: by "does not work" I mean does not execute the order, all the code runs perfectly fine but the order does not execute